# How to vertically center the cells of one column in a TikZ matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-matrix

Is it possible to vertically center the cells of one column in a TikZ matrix? Adding `nodes = {anchor = center}` vertically centers all of the cells, but I would like to retain the bottom alignment of the content of the cells in the second and third column.

That is, how can I vertically center `asdf` in the first column but retain the bottom alignment of the images in the second and third columns?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes]{
    asdf & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `column 1/.style` to style just the cells in the first column, or `row 2 column 3/.style` for a particular cell.  Here some styling applied to the first column:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    column 1/.style={anchor=center,color=red,text depth=2cm}]{
    asdf & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} \\
    bkgi & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```